# Send Email notification First time date is created or date changed

Tags: workflow, opportunity, customsetting

Send Email notification First time date is created or when that particular date changed , date comes from external system to salesforce opportunity object.

I Created a workflow rule with Ischanged(Date Field), it effects only when date is changed but not at the creation.

Please let me if any one knows how to specify criteria or rule for this

Note : For one object there will be many SO created but we need to send notification when first time date is entered and when ever the first time date entered is edited. We should not send notifications for other SO dates

Comment: Try using : ISBLANK(DateField) OR ISCHANGED(DATEFIELD)

Answer (score 0):

```
OR(ISNEW(), ISCHANGED(Functional_Date__c))
```

Use this formula

Comment: This formula will always return false. `ISCHANGED` will only ever return true on update.